# how to extract rows from matrix based on value in first entry?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This is another simple 'matrix' question in Mathematica. I want to show how I did this, and ask if there is a better answer.

I want to select all 'rows' from matrix based on value in the first column (or any column, I used first column here just as an example).

Say, find all rows where the entry in the first position is <=4 in this example:

```
    list = {{1, 2, 3},
           {4, 5, 8},
           {7 , 8, 9}}
```

So, the result should be

```
            {{1,2,3},
             {4,5,8}}
```

Well, the problem is I need to use Position, since the result returned by Position can be used directly by Extract. (but can't be used by Part or [[ ]], so that is why I am just looking at Position[] ).

But I do not know how to tell Position to please restrict the 'search' pattern to only the 'first' column so I can do this in one line.

When I type

```
pos = Position[list, _?(# <= 4 &)]
```

it returns position of ALL entries which are <=4.

```
{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}}
```

If I first get the first column, then apply Position on it, it works ofcourse

```
  list = {{1, 2, 3},
          {4, 5, 8},
          {7 , 8, 9}};
   pos = Position[list[[All, 1]], _?(# <= 4 &)]
   Extract[list, pos]
   -->       {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 8}}
```

Also I tried this:

```
pos = Position[list, _?(# <= 4 &)];
pos = Select[pos, #[[2]] == 1 &]  (*only look at ones in the 'first' column*)

{{1, 1}, {2, 1}}--->
```

and this gives me the correct positions in the first column. To use that to find all rows, I did

```
pos = pos[[All, 1]] (* to get list of row positions*)
---> {1, 2}

list[[ pos[[1]] ;; pos[[-1]], All]]
{{1, 2, 3}, 
 {4, 5, 8}}
```

So, to **summarize**, putting it all together, this is what I did:

### method 1

```
 list = {{1, 2, 3},
         {4, 5, 8},
         {7 , 8, 9}};
 pos = Position[list[[All, 1]], _?(# <= 4 &)]
 Extract[list, pos]
  -->       {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 8}}
```

### method 2

```
list = {{1, 2, 3},
      {4, 5, 8},
      {7 , 8, 9}}

pos = Position[list, _?(# <= 4 &)];
pos = Select[pos, #[[2]] == 1 &];
pos = pos[[All, 1]];
list[[ pos[[1]] ;; pos[[-1]], All]]

{{1, 2, 3}, 
{4, 5, 8}}

 The above clearly is not too good.
```

Is method 1 above the 'correct' functional way to do this?

For reference, this is how I do the above in Matlab:

```
EDU>> A=[1 2 3;4 5 8;7 8 9]
A =
     1     2     3
     4     5     8
     7     8     9

EDU>> A( A(:,1)<=4 , :)

     1     2     3
     4     5     8
```

I am trying to improve my 'functional' handling of working with matrices in Mathematica commands, this is an area I feel I am not good at working with lists. I find working with matrices easier for me.

The question is: Is there is a shorter/more functional way to do this in Mathematica?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the rows that meet the criteria, use `Cases`:

```
Cases[list, {n_, __} /; n <= 4]

(* {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 8}} *)
```

If you want the positions within the list rather than the rows themselves, use `Position` instead of `Cases` (restricted to the first level only):

```
Position[list, {n_, __} /; n <= 4, {1}]

(* {{1}, {2}} *)
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use [Pick[]](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pick.html) as follows:

```
Pick[list, list[[All, 1]], _?(# <= 4 &)]
```

Comment: Nice, +1. I had forgotten about `Pick`. You could also use `Pick[list, Thread[list[[All, 1]] <= 4]]`. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 5):

How about the following?

```
In[1]:= list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 8}, {7, 8, 9}};

In[2]:= Select[list, First[#] <= 4 &]

Out[2]= {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 8}}
```

Here's a loose translation of your matlab code:

```
list[[Flatten[Position[Thread[list[[All, 1]] <= 4], True]]]]
```

(of course, the `Flatten` would not be needed if I used `Extract` instead of `Part`).

Comment: that is the first thing I tried ! but I get an error, I guess because I used this form: pos = Position[list, _?(First[#] <= 4 &)] and this gives error: "Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[1]." even though, the strange thing, is that it still returns {{1},{2}}. But since I get the above error, I did not use it, as I still did not understand what this error mean.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just saw you used 'select' not 'position'. I actually wanted to just use Position, because it returns 'indices' and I wanted to use those for more general things. That is why I did not consider Select[] at all.

Comment: @Nasser: That error occurs because `Position`, by default, looks at all levels of an expression. You have to restrict the level and/or head, e.g. `Position[list, _List?(First[#] <= 4 &), {1}]`

Comment: @Simon Only level restriction doesn't help, you have to add the Heads option: `Position[list, _?(First[#] <= 4 &), {1}, Heads -> False]`

Comment: @Simon, that was it! the trick with the level. That is why I was getting the error. Else I would have used it. I did not think of the level. Btw, I works ok with just '1' there at the end and not {1}. May be {1} is more general. Need to look into that.  btw, how do make text as 'code' in comment? is there a short-key for that?, I do not see {} anywhere to click on to make text appear as code when adding comment. thanks.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Thanks! I knew that restricting just level wasn't working... but I since I hadn't finished my coffee or breakfast, my brain didn't think of the `Heads` option.  @Nasser `1` searches up to level `1`, `{1}` searches only level `1`.  The comments support a restricted set of [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). Code is delimited by backticks: `\`code\``

Comment: Maybe `Position[#[[1]] <= 4 & /@ list, True]` ?

Answer (score 4):

There is a faster method than those already presented, using `SparseArray`.  It is:

```
list ~Extract~
  SparseArray[UnitStep[4 - list[[All, 1]]]]["NonzeroPositions"]
```

Here are speed comparisons with the other methods.  I had to modify WReach's method to handle other position specifications.

```
f1[list_, x_] := Cases[list, {Sequence @@ Table[_, {x - 1}], n_, ___} /; n <= 4]
f2[list_, x_] := Select[list, #[[x]] <= 4 &]
f3[list_, x_] := Pick[list, (#[[x]] <= 4 &) /@ list]
f4[list_, x_] := Pick[list, UnitStep[4 - list[[All, x]]], 1]
f5[list_, x_] := Pick[list, Thread[list[[All, x]] <= 4]]
f6[list_, x_] := list ~Extract~
                   SparseArray[UnitStep[4 - list[[All, x]]]]["NonzeroPositions"]
```

For a table with few rows and many columns (comparing position 7):

```
a = RandomInteger[99, {250, 150000}];
timeAvg[#[a, 7]] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6} // Column
```

```
0.02248
0.0262
0.312
0.312
0.2808
0.0009728
```

For a table with few columns and many rows (comparing position 7):

```
a = RandomInteger[99, {150000, 12}];
timeAvg[#[a, 7]] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6} // Column
```

```
0.0968
0.1434
0.184
0.0474
0.103
0.002872
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be very clever:

```
Pick[list, UnitStep[4 - list[[All, 1]]], 1]
```

This also avoids unpacking, which means it'll be faster and use less memory.